# Fetch a requested encoded parameter in UTF-8 JSF

Tags: java, http, jsf, encoding, utf-8

I have a problem to get a requested query param encoded in `UTF-8`

**Request URL**

localhost:8080/page?searchKey=%D9%85

**Query String Parameters**

searchKey:م

when tried to get this requested param by this code:

```
 String searchKey=((HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()).getParameter("searchKey");
if (!StringUtil.isEmpty(searchKey)) {
    try {
        System.out.println("SearchKey--------Before-------------------"+searchKey);
       searchKey=URLDecoder.decode(searchKey, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {

    }
    System.out.println("SearchKey---------------------------" + searchKey);
    }
```

these two `system.out` prints the following :

SearchKey--------Before-------------------�? // a square shape

SearchKey----------after-----------------�? // a square shape

So I need to catch :%D9%85 value which is request to decode it as `UTF-8` so how to do that

I can fetch it from `((HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()).getQueryString()` but that will be a huge effort is there another way to fetch this encoded utf parmeter

HINT: Language used is Arabic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request parameters as available by `HttpServletRequest#getParameter()` (and its JSF flavored facade `ExternalContext#getRequestParameterMap()` which you should actually be using instead of polluting your JSF beans with `javax.servlet.*` artifacts, or better, the `@ManagedProperty` or `<f:viewParam>`, but that aside) are **already** decoded by the container. You don't need to pass them through `URLDecoder` once again. If you want to get the raw parameters so that you can decode them yourselves, then you should indeed be using `HttpServletRequest#getQueryString()` instead and be parsing the parameter name-value pairs yourself.

In your particular case, it appears that the container is using the wrong encoding to decode the query string parameter. Most containers indeed naively default to ISO-8859-1 as mandated by HTTP 1.1 which indeed isn't from this decade anymore.

So, basically, you need to explicitly tell your container to use UTF-8 instead to decode the query string parameters. Unfortunately you didn't tell anywhere which container you're using, so I can't answer that in detail. I'll assume Tomcat as a general example: you need to edit its `/conf/server.xml` to add the `URIEncoding` attribute to the `<Connector>` element with a value of `UTF-8`.

```xml
<Connector ... URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

If you're using a different container, just consult its documentation using the new keywords which you just learnt from this answer.

Comment: Thanks so much I was wondering why I need to decode it too 
.It is the tomcat I solved by placing ``URIEnoding`` in ``<Connector..``

Comment: ``<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                       connectionTimeout="20000"
                       redirectPort="8443"  URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>``

Answer (score 1):

1. Donot decode request parameter by yourself. Container already did it.
2. Depends on container you used, read document to know how to configure parameter encoding.
3. There are 2 kind of parameter encodings. Form parameter encoding and Query string parameter encoding. For Query string parameter encoding ( Like your case ), If you using Glassfish, you can configure like this in WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml

   ```
   <glassfish-web-app>
        <context-root>/webApp</context-root>
        <parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8" />
   </glassfish-web-app>
   ```